# How to pass data from table in JSP to Java controller?

Tags: java, jsp

Please help me to solve a problem! 
I have table created in JSP and filled with data from my DB, and the problem is - I have not idea how to access that JSP data from my controller.
For example - I need to pass appropriate ID (just String) to my controller from JSP to execute Delete method.

My jsp:

```
<body>
<form action="/editCategory" method="POST">
<h3>Existing categories</h3>
<%
    List<Category> categories = (List<Category>) request.getAttribute("model");
    if (categories != null) {
%>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th width="24">ID</th>
        <th width="80">Name</th>
        <%--<th></th>--%>
    </tr>
    <%
        for (Category category : categories) {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= category.getId() %> <% request.setAttribute("id", category.getId());%>
        </td>
        <td><%= category.getName() %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
<%
} else {
%>
<b>Categories list is empty :(</b>
<%
    }
%>

</form>
</body>
```

My controller methods:

```
public Model getModel(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws DBException
    {
        if (req.getParameter("submit")!=null){
            addCategory(req);
        }

        if (req.getParameter("delete")!=null){
            deleteCategory(req);
        }
        categories = categoryDAO.getCategories();
        return new Model("/editCategory.jsp", categories);

    }

private void deleteCategory(HttpServletRequest req) {
        System.out.println(req.getAttribute("id") + " printed");
    }
```

For now I want just to see that correct ID is taken!
Please help!

Comment: you need to use html's `input` to send form parameters to pass values...

Comment: sorry, but how I understand - input affect on how my html will be displayed in browser. But I want to avoid it

Comment: d answer below is the correct way of doing it using a hidden field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it this way:

```
<%
    for (Category category : categories) {
%>
<tr>
    <td><%= category.getId() %>
    <input type="hidden" name="allIds" value="<%= category.getId() %>" /></td>
    <td><%= category.getName() %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<%
    }
%>
```

as the type says `hidden` is not visible.
after that read the values in your servlet with:

```
String[] lAllIds = request.getParameterValues("allIds");
```

Comment: Thanks! ..I knew that the answer will be simple  - never worked with html)

Comment: Accepted.
But may be you know how to take just one ID? Appropriate ID for Delete button in the table line... ? =)

Comment: with input of type checkbox. add a checkbox for each line. name = deletedIds. If the checkbox is checked the value will be passed to your servlet. read it with getParameterValues and you will have the id's that must be deleted.